# Localize vendor plugin with CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, plugins, localization, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I would like to use the cakephp-users plugin in my CakePHP 3.3.3 based application, and I would like to localize that.

I am using composer to autoload the plugin.

If my understanding of the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files) is correct than the Plugin localization po file shall be the vendor/cakemanager/cakephp-users/src/Locale/hu/users.po in my case. (The path should be correct  because the

```
    bin/cake i18n extract --plugin Users
```

command generates the default.pot file to vendor/cakemanager/cakephp-users//src/Locale folder.)

The text did not get localized regardless if I use the default.po filename or users.po filename. If I move a translation to the application's localization file (src/Locale/hu/default.po) then my strings got translated. (After I delete the tmp/cache/persistent folder's contents.)

Is there anything special what I miss to get my plugin localized?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Third party plugin localization should be in the apps `Locale` folder

Your assumption that the files should be in the plugin folder is not necessarily correct. Custom localizations for third party code should be in the applications `Locale` folder, otherwise they would get lost everytime the code package is being updated.

You may want to [**report the behavior**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) that the shell by default wants to extract all plugin localization into the plugins `Locale` folder as an issue. Personally I think it would be good if it wouldn't try that in case the plugin lives in the `vendors` folder.

Until that, you should use the `--output` option to specifiy the proper path to your applications `Locale` folder.

### First party plugin localization *might* go in the plugins `Locale` folder

If it were your own plugin, and you wanted to ship it with ready made translations, then they should be in the plugins `Locale` folder, however nothing should be added afterwards if the plugin is a standalone plugin that is being included via composer, because again, these changes would get lost on update.

You should only add further localizations in a plugins `Locale` folder in case the plugin is tied directly to your application, and therefore lives in the applications `plugins` folder.

### `cakemanager/cakephp-users` doesn't follow the conventions

All that being said, `cakemanager/cakephp-users` is a special case, it doesn't follow the conventions of using domain translation methods like `__d()`, and supplying a domain name that is the lowercased, underscored variant of the plugin name, like `__d('users', 'message text')`.

Instead it uses domain less translation calls, ie `__('message text')`, see for example

**[https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-users/...src/Controller/UsersController.php#L75](https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-users/blob/8ca2a985dc0e73c9bbbdb0d9cc101b28407c2b02/src/Controller/UsersController.php#L75)**

Therefore CakePHPs message file loader will never try to load any localization files from the plugins `Locale` folder in the first place, and it also won't look up proper separate localization files in your apps `Locale` folder.

So with this specific plugin, in its current form, the translations have to go in your applications default translation file.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Language Files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files)**